# Column space and general solution span

Tags: linear-algebra

Please refer to the picture attached. How can a column space of $\mathbb R^2$ have a general solution in $\mathbb R^3$? the solution spans a higher Dimension than the column space.
Or there is something wrong with my statements in the picture?

[Ref pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixSHG.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It can't. Since your columns are 2-tuples, the column space here has to be subspace of $R^2$ (or $R^2$ itself).

Comment: What do you mean by 'general solution' of column space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C(A)$ is $\mathbb R^2\subset \mathbb R^2$, as $A$ is $2×5$ and has rank $2$...
The kernel, by the Rank-nullity theorem,  has dimension $3$, and sits in $\mathbb R^5$...

Remember,  $A$ is $n×m$ means $T_A:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$.  Thus the kernel is a subspace of $\mathbb R^m$, and the image, $C(A)$, is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$...

Answer (score 1):

You have a $2\times 5$ matrix $A$. Its column space is $\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ (actually they are equal), and its *kernel* or solution space is $\subseteq\Bbb R^{\bf5}$, consisting of those vectors $v$ which make $Av=0$.
 We can perform a multiplication $AB$ only if $B$ is a $5\times n$ matrix for some $n$.